# Anagrams lintcode

Tags: java

> Given an array of strings, return all groups of strings that are anagrams.
>
> Given ["lint", "intl", "inlt", "code"], return ["lint", "inlt", "intl"].
>
> Given ["ab", "ba", "cd", "dc", "e"], return ["ab", "ba", "cd", "dc"].

my code was like this but it gave the error msg at `"stringb.add(aString));"`; I couldn4t figure out why.

```
{
    /**
     * @param strs: A list of strings
     * @return: A list of strings
     */

    private int hash(int[] count){
        int hash = 0;
        int primeA = 378551;
        int primeB = 378559;
        //int result = 0;
        for(int aNumber: count){
            hash = hash*primeA + aNumber;
            primeA = primeA*PrimeB;
        }
    } 
    public List<String> anagrams(String[] strs) {
        // write your code here
        int i = 0;
        int l = 0;
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> strings  = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

        for(String aString : strs){
            int[] charCount = new int[26];
            for(i = 0; i<aString.length(); i++){
                charCount[aString.charAt[i]-'a']++;
            }
            l = hash(charCount);
            if(!strings.containsKey(l)){
                strings.put(l,new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            ArrayList<String> stringb = strings.get(l);
            stringb.add(aString));

        }
        for(ArrayList<String> aList: strings.values()){
                if(aList.size()>1){
                    result.addAll(aList);
                }
        }
        result result;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace _stringb.add(aString));_ for _stringb.add(aString);_

Comment: You have an extra parentheses on `stringb.add(aString));`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Oh..Thanks for the reply! one more question, the big prime integer is big enough, will there be risk that the hash value exceed the upper limit of integer?